# Copy directory, but only update files if needed

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code:

```
my.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(path, path, true)
```

However, I think this copies the entire directory even if one single file is changed in a directory. Is this true?

If so, is there any validation I can put it to say only update the file not the entire folder? My application is going to be run on a network with about 300 computers each copying over 300 MB, so it could cause the network to crash or slow if it is trying to copy over ever directory everytime even if only one file is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to execute in an hidden command prompt the command XCOPY.

For example:

```
xcopy d:\temp d:\temp2 /D /Y
```

will copy every modified file from the source dir to destination dir without asking for overwrite confirmations

You could write something like this

```
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C xcopy d:\temp d:\temp2 /D /Y"
        Dim proc = new Process()
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo
        proc.Start()
```

Comment: Ohh brilliant do I use this instead of the copy one? the two d:\ are they the source path and destination path?
What is the d: part for...... sorry this is the first time ive done something like this

Comment: of course d:\temp and d:\temp2 are source and dest folder, change with your specs. /D means copy only newest files. /Y means, don't prompt me and overwrite the dest files

Comment: I can seem to get it to work :/ Do I post another question asking what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As you wish, but what is the error? To debug you could try to change the /C in /K and remove the Hidden style. In this way the command window will be visible with the output of any error message

Comment: Ive managed to get it saving files but not directories :/ I'll keep debugging see if I can sort it out. thanks

Comment: Have you added the /S switch? (Copy folder and subfolder excluding the empty ones)

Comment: Brilliant added it and then had it in the wrong order. Now when I run it for he files that are being copied it asks if it is file or directory, is there a switch/command that makes it only a file?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Well, you can open a command prompt and type XCOPY /? and you get all the possibilities available. Also you could try another command usually available on Win7 called ROBOCOPY